# Check if quotes are pressed inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file that includes a textbox in it. I was just wondering how I would be able to check if the user types `"`, if so then run a function... I've been looking up examples and source code but have had no luck so far.. This is what I have so far though.

```
<script>
function turnTextGreen(e) {
    var keyNum = e.keyCode;
    var userString = e.toString;

    if (keyNum == "222") {

        do{

            userString.fontcolor("green");

        }while (e.keyNum != "222");
    }
};
</script>
```

Then in my textbox area I have this:

```
<textarea class="text_edit" id="my_text" onfocus="return turnTextGreen(event)" 
</textarea>
```

I am a beginner in javascript and html so I hope this is enough info to help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't look at the key, look at the value: `if (/"/.test(textarea.value) /* do stuff */`, that way you catch text that is pasted or dragged to the textarea.

Comment: Side note, your opening textarea tag is missing the `>`.

Comment: @RobG I understand what you're saying but not how to put it into code lol.. would that catch the `""'s` ?

Comment: You can't just sniff keystrokes, you need to parse the value of the textarea because the " might be inserted anywhere (or by various means), not necessarily at the end. Maybe you just want to turn the text green while there are an uneven number of " characters, and not green when there are an even number? Doing this well is probably a lot more difficult than you think. :-)

Comment: I'm trying to replicate how VS automatically turns `strings` green when you type a `"`.  Then it stops the green font when you type the closing `"`

Comment: You can't do that inside a textarea element as markup isn't allowed there. You can use say a DIV with the [*contenteditable* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html) set to true. And you have to parse the content, you can't just respond to key presses (unless you expect users to never use a delete, backspace, cursor keys, etc.). Sorry, but this really isn't trivial. BTW, to get the " character from the related event, you need `event.keyCode == 222 && event.shiftKey`. That gets the related key and whether the shift key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup) event, so that you can check whether `e.char` is `"` once the user has typed the key.

```
<textarea class="text_edit" id="my_text" onkeyup="turnTextGreen"></textarea>
```

---

**EDIT**

It seems that `char` is not implemented so in the event handler you still need to check for the key code using the `which` property as suggested in the answer by ventsi.slav. This would still not guarantee that the char inserted is actually a `"` since the key code is also `222` when the alternative character for that key is inserted.

As pointed out in the comments this approach also doesn't take into account insertions through pasting with the context menu Paste option. Still, using the `keyup` event is a first attempt on which you can iterate until you reach a solution that's good for your use case. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYder/1/) on which you can start to work and experiment.

Comment: And if the character is pasted rather than typed? Using the context menu won't dispatch a key event.

Comment: He specifically asked 'check if the user types " ', which is not the same as 'check if the content of the textarea contains " '.

He could well have asked the wrong question though :)

Comment: For right now I just need if the user types `"` I can worry about if the content contains `"` later on

Comment: The `char` property returns the string but it seems to be [unimplemented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680830) so we are left with the `which` property and back to checking the key code.